# fullcalendar doesnt trigger eventRender after resize to same duration

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have to update a bar at the same moment as the duration of an event has been changed.
its working well with the callback `eventRender` but there is a strange behaviour in a specific case.

E.g.

- The current duration of the event is 2 days.
- I resize it to 3 days -> eventRender
- the mouse button is still down!
- resize it back to 2 days -> no callback!

There is my problem that i now dont recognize this resize and my bar will not be refreshed!

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events:[
                {
                    id:"1",
                    title:'Event',
                    start:'{{ date }}'
                }],
            selectable:true,
            editable:true,
            allDay:true,
            eventRender:function(event, element, view){

                $('#log').append("test");

                //update bar
            }

        });
```

Are there some other events that i could use or is this just a normal behaviour ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `eventRender` does not render when you resize back to the original period of the event. I do not know if this is a normal behavior or not.
This is not ideal but you 'could' couple `eventRender` with `eventResizeStop` to detect when the event has been resized, even to its original period.

Here's a fiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/94d050me/